# How to know physical memory addresses which is accessed by CPUs in the Linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, qemu, mmu

I'm trying to trace memory access patterns by some benchmark application in Linux. Ultimately, I want to know physical memory address which is accessed by CPUs in the kernel(or user) space.

Is there a simple way to get it without modification the kernel source? I hope that it is possible to hook some MMU routine in my kernel module, and then translate the virtual address to the physical address, and write the physical addresses to kernel log or something like that. Is this possible?

Is it better to use some simulator like a Qemu?

Comment: There is no simple way, and the kernel is free to e.g. swap-out some portion of RAM and reuse it at any time. If you only want to know about virtual memory mapping, consider `/proc/1234/maps` for process 1234.

Comment: The Linux kernel gives processes **virtual** address spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to know which physical memory is accessed by the benchmark application, more specifically, whether the access pattern is uniformly distributed in the physical memory or not.

Comment: It seems to me that your question might have no sense. What exactly does "uniformly distributed access pattern" means? Do you have a NUMA hardware system? And what about the on-chip processor cache??

Comment: You also should explain why are you asking that question.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah go for QEMU, it is best suited for your requirement. You will have to tweak QEMU code to get the translation from Virtual addressed to physical addresses. Only thing is QEMU is for research purpose so you might not be able to get the exact mapping behavior as real system will do. But still, it will fulfill your purpose to some extent.